# Does staring at a screen for long periods of time cause myopia?

Tags: eye, cause-and-effect, eyelids, myopia-nearsightedness, screen-time-limits

My uncle once told me "the real reason myopia happens because you look at a PC monitor non stop for hours. When you look to the same object for hours, the eye muscles gets used to the focusing close objects and since they bend the eyes exactly the same for long periods the eye itself changes its shape so look to the distant mountains regularly and blink your eyes so your eyeballs will be wet"

It sounds somewhat illogical but the myopia illustrations on the web shows eyes with faulty lenses And oval shaped eyeballs.

In short, is he true? Does long periods of gaming etc cause myopia?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gaming for long times cause myopia? It happens when you mantain your eyes focused in a small part without natural light and to stress them. Stress causes damage and lack of natural light cause blindness and sickness of the eyes.

The gaming monitor causes unnatural light which stress your eyes and cause you to do habits and actions which are not natural such as postures.

I would not say its the gaming per se but the habits that go along with gaming the ones which cause myopia.

I gonna say your uncle is right however and to do eye exercises regularly can help maintain good vision.

Comment: Please provide references to back up your statements, as what you are saying is not entirely correct.